# The V-calendar gives out a template or the rendering function is not defined in Laravel Vue, what should I do?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I imported v-kalendare, registered it in the components property and registered it in the blade template, but it gives me the error " [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.". I am using the vcalendar version "vcalendar": "^2.4.2" . I use the version for vue 2

My blade

```
<calendar-date-picker is-range v-model="date_range"></calendar-date-picker>
```

My js

```js
import CalendarDatePicker from 'v-calendar'

let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
...
   components:{
        CalendarDatePicker
    }
```

I also tried wrapping it in template - it didn't help

Comment: It's "vcalendar" in one place and "v-calendar" in another. You can see that default import is lib plugin and not a component, https://vcalendar.io/getting-started/installation.html#method-1-use-globally